# Noob Visual Studio Sharepoint 2013 Development

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Is it true that I have to have Server 2008 R2 or above and at minimum sharepoint2013 installed on my DEV box in order to create sharepoint projects?  I just downloaded the tools, and when I go to create a sharepoint project I get a "sharepoint not installed" error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are requirements for SharePoint2013

Windows Server

> Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (64 bit) Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter
>   Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate (64 bit) Standard, or Datacenter.

SQL Server

> SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (64 bit)
>   SQL Server 2012 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to create a sharepoint project with visual studio 2012 on my windows 7 development machine. I have an old version of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll from sharepoint 2010 deployed to the GAC and this is automatically referenced when I create a new project.

Obviously I can't run the code because I don't have sharepoint 2013 installed (this requires a server version of windows) but it's enough to create a sharepoint project and write some code and I even get sharepoint intellisense (though if you are developing for sharepoint 2013 you would be better off using a later version of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll).